# Why do modal dialogs in Prism 6 not support strong modal mode and behave themselves as non modal?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Sometimes, modal dialogs in Prism 6 for WPF behave themselves as non-modal. For example if a modal dialog is over its parent window and I click on the surface of parent (near the modal dialog's border) then the parent obstructs the modal dialog, so after it I see the modal dialog's parent window not the modal dialog itself on the screen. Is there a way to create strong modal dialogs in Prism 6 WPF MVVM application or I should use WPF MesageBox dialog class to get strong modal dialogs in such application?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PopupWindowAction with IsModal=true property.

Make sure you are using the latest Prism version 6.2 which contains a fix for setting the dialog window owner: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes-6.2.0, fix #228: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/228

Comment: Please give me a reference to examples of using modal dialogs in Prism 6.2 for WPF.

Comment: [Interactivity QuickStart](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/InteractivityQuickstart) Make sure to use Nuget to update this sample to 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the PopupWindowAction.IsModal property?

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/45-AdvancedMVVMScenarios.md#using-behaviors-to-implement-the-interaction-user-experience

Comment: I've set this property.

Comment: Make sure you're using Prism 6.2

Comment: I've updated all Prism libraries in my application to Prism 6.2.